# How to get a specific number of cells using an array formula in Google Sheets

Tags: arrays, if-statement, google-sheets, split, google-sheets-formula

I want to pre-process my data like the Result section of the attached image before flattening and using it.

I want to write an array formula in the cells marked in blue. How do I get results?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(COLUMN(A2:D5)<=F2:F5; A2:D5; ))
```

[image]